# Setting up a proxy that performs client certificate authentication to a remote server

Tags: linux, proxy, ssl, client-certificates

I am setting up an infrastructure where I have an nginx web server configured to require a client certificate for access to a resource.

However, the clients do not themselves have support for client certificates (it's pip, and we can't modify it to support the certificates [even though this is easy given it's Python, but still]).

Basically, the idea I had would be to setup a proxy on each machine that can do the certificate authentication to the remote server… but I really don't know how easy this is, or how I would go about it. Ideally, the proxy would be as lightweight as possible.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider using [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) as your proxy, it's a highly flexible SSL proxy, which can do client certificate authentication.

Comment: Thanks… very helpful. I didn't know stunnel could be run in "client mode" like that.